# Matlab :: Change Day, Month Year of serial date number

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to change the Day, Month and Year of a serial date number in matlab

e.g.: 7.367985930307407e+05

gives me 13-Apr-2017 14:13:57.

I need:  **01-Jan-2017** 14:13:57

I get the serial date number from a simulink model, where is a matlab emb. code block with:

```
function t = sysTime

coder.extrinsic('now'); 
t=0;

t = now
end
```

Anyone can help? Read the matlab datenum and now docu but I still couldnt figure it out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) object to alter specific portions of the date

```
d = 7.367985930307407e+05;

dt = datetime(datevec(d));  
dt.Month = 1;
dt.Day = 1;
%   01-Jan-2017 14:13:57

% And if you need the serial date number back:
result = datenum(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function sysTime, the output is set to `now`, which gives you the current time as returned by your system. Try the following instead:

```
function t = sysTime

coder.extrinsic('now'); 
t=0;

t=datenum(2017,1,1) + rem(now,1);

end
```

Matlab date numbers are numbers of type double that represent the number of days since a reference date. Thus, the number before the decimal point gives you a date, the nubers after the decimal point give you the time of day.

With the `datenum` function you can get the date number for your desired date and add the fractional part of the system time to get what you want. In the long run it would probably be better to parameterize your reference date in the matlab block.